# swapping production schemas in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I have existing schema called current_schema.I receive fresh 3rd party data every few hours. I want to replace data in it every few hours and here's what I am planning to do

1- write that fresh data to postgres temp schema
2- rename current_schema to current_schema_del
3- rename temp to current_schema
4- delete current_schema_del

Now, what will happen if someone tries to access/modify data when I am performing step 2 and 3? Is this the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 3):

Your procedure should work fine.

As step 2, you can also delete the old schema right away.

Deleting will require `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` locks on the schema and all objects in it, so it will have to wait until all earlier transactions accessing these objects are done.

One option is to employ a function (with `SECURITY DEFINER` and owned by a superuser) that kills all transactions that access such objects so that you don't have to wait for long running transactions to end.